# How to curl images to specific folder/directory

Tags: curl, xargs

I am using this code:

xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt

to download all image urls from text file.

All images are downloading to home directory.

How can I specify the folder/directory to download to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl has no specific option to specify the download directory for `-O`. The standard fix for that is to simply make your command line first `cd` to the directory you've chosen to download the files into.

Maybe something like this:

```
#!bin/sh
# figure out where we are
pwd=`pwd`

# go to the download directory
cd /tmp/my-downloads

# Download into the right dir, find the URL file in the original dir
xargs -n 1 curl -O < $pwd/urls.txt
```